# How to open a Kibana chart by clicking on another chart's element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kibana, kibana-4

I'm trying to create a custom visualization plugin for Kibana 4.6, I've made a copy of the default pie chart in the 'installed plugins' folder. I'm trying to to show another chart (a histogram/vertical bar chart) after a click on any slice of the pie chart. 
I'm sure that it isn't the best way to do it, but right now, I've found only one way to add a custom click handler to a pie chart slice: to insert the following code inside ui/public/vislib/visualizations/pie_chart.js (inside the PieChart.prototype.addPath method):

```
path.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        // my custom onclick action will be here
    }
});
```

However, I can't figure out how to create a histogram in that function. I've tried requiring 'ui/Vis/Schemas', 'ui/vislib/vis', 'ui/vislib_vis_type/VislibVisType' and creating a new VislibVisType and a new Vis, the idea was to run VislibVisType.prototype.createRenderbot, but it seems that I don't have the needed objects to pass as arguments (vis, $el, uiState).
I'm really new to Kibana (and AngularJS), so I'm probably doing it all wrong, so I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be going about creating a custom Kibana plugin incorrectly. Tim Roes has an excellent series that can help you get started.

https://www.timroes.de/2015/12/02/writing-kibana-4-plugins-basics/

There are two types of plugins: apps and visualizations. What you are describing might not be possible as a visualization (or maybe I'm wrong), so you might consider creating an app.

Once you get going, you might want to look into C3.js and the pie chart in that library. it has a click handler which you should be able to tap into. There is also a bar chart in that library.